# Asana Slack Integration - List only my tasks

Tags: asana, slack, zapier

When I do `/asana list` I get every task in all projects.

Is it possible to do `/asana list @member` to show tasks only assigned to me or `/asana list To My Tasks` to show tasks in a project only? All this without using Zapier?

Comment: I'm looking for the same

Comment: ... without using Zapier?  When why tag the question 'zapier'?

Comment: I was hoping for an update by the people who wrote the tutorial, like "You can do this using Asana only now by ...."